# Random access to video frame by its id

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, ffprobe

I have a 24 hour video and would like to organize storage of some meta information (particularly bounding boxes of objects) for arbitrary frame. It implies that I must have a reliable random access to frame by its id, practically even to the range of frames in a way `(id_start, id_end)`.

Once again, it is critically to get the same frame when I fill meta storage and when I will get meta later (in general in another environment - ffmpeg version, codecs etc). Otherwise I will put bounding box on the wrong frame.

So there ways I found

1. `ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf select='between(n,x,y)' -vsync 0 frames%d.png`
   The problem is it works too slow. Also I don't know is it reliable in sense of reproducing.
2. `ffmpeg -ss pkt_pts_time -i in.mp4 -vframes n output_%03d.png`
   where `pkt_pts_time` got from `ffprobe -show_frames in.mp4 -select_streams v`
   The problem is pkt_pts_time not clear at all. Does pkt_pts_time refer to -ss parameter?

Actually the question is - does internal meta information of frame (say h.264) contain frame id? I didn't find way to get it.

Now I am thinkig to store png md5sum for each T's frame (anchor). Later I will be able to check consistency using them.

Can anyone suggest something better?

Answer (score 2):

*does internal meta information of frame (say h.264) contain frame id? I didn't find way to get it.*

No. In a MP4, you can seek using a timestamp.

```
ffmpeg -ss pkt_pts_time -i in.mp4 -vsync 0 -vframes n output_%03d.png
```

where first output frame is the first input frame having pts_time equal or after the `-ss` value, e.g. if there's a frame with pts_time 4.36 then `-ss 4.36` will start with that frame. But if there's no frame at 4.36, but there's one at 4.38, then your command with `-ss 4.36` will output the `4.38` frame first.

Comment: `You can seek using a timestamp` yes, noobs gotta learn... A frame's ID is its own (unique) timestamp since one frame represents one moment in time.